# Snippet displaying LearnDash parent course title with lesson title

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I am using LearnDash on my WordPress site, and have created the following snippet to get a list of all lessons:

```
function get_list_of_lessons_class(){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sfwd-lessons',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($q->have_posts()) : 
        while ($q->have_posts()) :  $q->the_post();
        the_title();
        endwhile; 
    else:
        ;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
return $finalout;
}
add_shortcode('get_list_of_lessons', 'get_list_of_lessons_class');
```

Can anyone advise please how to display the course title of each lesson beside the lesson title?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current post's course ID from [learndash_get_course_id()](https://developers.learndash.com/function/learndash_get_course_id/), e.g.

```php
$course_id = learndash_get_course_id();
if (isset($course_id) && $course_id) echo esc_html(get_the_title($course_id));
```

Under the covers it's stored in a post meta value course_id, but you might as well use their helper function to read it.

Comment: Thank you very much Rup!